# Send Multiple objects with Ajax to the ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have one ViewModel that contains three Collection of `ExternalProjectViewModel`, `CertificateUniverSityViewModel`, `CertificateInstitutionsViewModel`.

**CreateFreelancerProfileViewModel.cs**

```
public class CreateFreelancerProfileViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    // More ...
   public List<ExternalProjectViewModel> ExternalProjects { get; set; }   

   public List<CertificateUniverSityViewModel> CertificateUniverSitys { get; set; }

   public List<CertificateInstitutionsViewModel> CertificateInstitutions { get; set; }

}
```

**My Ajax code:**

```
            $('#Controller').on('click','#SaveProfile',

            function() {

                debugger;
                var CertificateInstitutions = 
                    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("CertificateInstitutionsListLocal"));

                var CertificateUniverSitys = 
                    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("CertificateUniverSitysListLocal"));

                var ExternalProjects = 
                    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ExProjectListLocal"));

                $.ajax({
                    url : '@Url.Action(MVC.Freelancer.Profile.CreatePrfile())',
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {
                        ExternalProjects,
                        CertificateUniverSitys,
                        CertificateInstitutions
                    }
                });


            });
```

When I Want Send Objects to Controller, First Get It from [LocalStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)
And After Get it Send it to Controller Action:

```
 public virtual ActionResult CreatePrfile(CreateFreelancerProfileViewModel viewModel)
```

When I see `viewModel` Values Show My Objects Count That is 2 but Objects Properties is null.so that my server object properties name equally with the client Object properties name.

**LocalStorage Values**

```
[{"ExternalProjects":{"Name":"wqeqwe","Body":"wqewqe","Url":‌​"wqewqe"}}]

[{"CertificateUniverSity":{"Name":"sad","Description":"sadas‌​","DateOfGets":"sad"‌​,"CertificateType":"‌​2","Field":"sadasd",‌​"UniName":"sad","Cer‌​tificateUniverSityLe‌​vel":"2"}}]
```

Comment: capture that post request in your browser and see

Comment: @Steve I do This Work in client side object properties is fill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could send them as JSON payload:

```
$.ajax({
    url : '@Url.Action(MVC.Freelancer.Profile.CreatePrfile())',
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        externalProjects: ExternalProjects,
        certificateUniverSitys: CertificateUniverSitys,
        certificateInstitutions: CertificateInstitutions
    }),
    success: function(result) {
        alert('data sent successfully');
    }
});
```

This assumes that the instances you got from the localStorage of those 3 variables represent javascript arrays with the corresponding objects in it.

Comment: I try Your Code But it does not change

Comment: Could you show the exact payload that gets sent to the server? I suspect that the `ExternalProjects`, `CertificateUniverSitys` and `CertificateInstitutions` that you got from the local storage do not represent javascript arrays.

Comment: I'd guess we the `case` should match the `class` properties. Try using `ExternalProjects: ExternalProjects,` instead of `externalProjects: ExternalProjects,` (this is just a shot in the dark).

Comment: No, the JSON serializer will handle the casing properly.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov `[{"ExternalProjects":{"Name":"wqeqwe","Body":"wqewqe","Url":"wqewqe"}}]`

Comment: @DarinDimitrov `[{"CertificateUniverSity":{"Name":"sad","Description":"sadas","DateOfGets":"sad","CertificateType":"2","Field":"sadasd","UniName":"sad","CertificateUniverSityLevel":"2"}}]`

Comment: OK, exactly as I thought. In your example `CertificateUniverSity` is not an array. You cannot possibly expect to be able to map it to a `List<CertificateUniverSityViewModel>` property on your server. So basically depending on your requirements you have 2 options: either modify the property on your view model so that it is not a list: `public CertificateUniverSityViewModel CertificateUniverSity { get; set; }` or fix your objects. If you want to send a list then your object should look like this on the client (see next comment):

Comment: Like this: `CertificateUniverSity = [{"Name":"sad","Description":"sadas‌​","DateOfGets":"sad"‌​,"CertificateType":"‌​2","Field":"sadasd",‌​"UniName":"sad","Cer‌​tificateUniverSityLe‌​vel":"2"}]` and also `ExternalProjects = [{"Name":"wqeqwe","Body":"wqewqe","Url":‌​"wqewqe"}]`. Basically you should have **javascript arrays** inside the 3 variables out there if you expect to be able to map them to lists on your server.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I Do, You Answer but again, it is null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133914/discussion-between-soheil-alizadeh-and-darin-dimitrov).