# Post More Than One Serialize Forms In One Ajax to Controller C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, serialization

I have 2 form that i want to post to controller using serialize concept at once. Is it possible to send more the one serialize form in one ajax to controller?
if it is, how can i do that?

this is my ajax/javascript:

```
    $('#btnSave').click(function () {
        debugger;
        var vDataHead = $('#frmHeader').serialize();
        var vDataDet = $('#frmDetail').serialize();


        if ($("#txtCompanyID").val() == "" || $("#txtBranchID").val() == "" || $("#txtUserID").val() == "")
        {
            debugger;
            Swal.fire('Error!', 'Please Fill All Fields to Save Budget Setting!', 'error');
        }
        else
        {
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                url: '/MappingUserItemGroup/SaveData',
                data: { dataHead: vDataHead, dataDet: vDataDet },
                method: 'POST',
                success: function (mdl)
                {
                    debugger;
                    if (mdl == "Exist")
                    {
                        debugger;
                        Swal.fire('Error!', 'Setting Mapping User Item Group Already Exist ', 'error');
                    }
                    else if (mdl == "Berhasil")
                    {
                        debugger;
                        Swal.fire('Success', 'Setting Mapping User Item Group Was Successfully Saved!', 'success').then(() => { loadTable();});
                    }
                    else if (mdl == "Gagal")
                    {
                        debugger;
                        Swal.fire('Error!', 'Setting Mapping User Item Group Failed To Be Saved!', 'error');
                    }
                },
                error: function (mdl)
                {
                    debugger;
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

and this is my controller:

```
public ActionResult SaveData(MapingUIGH dataHead, List<MapingUIGD> dataDet)
    {
        //do something here with that data serialize

    }
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41832057/send-multiple-objects-with-ajax-to-the-asp-net-mvc-controller

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send Multiple objects with Ajax to the ASP.NET MVC controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41832057/send-multiple-objects-with-ajax-to-the-asp-net-mvc-controller)

Comment: If you want submit 2 forms to same method then why can’t you merge the 2 forms into one single form?

Comment: @HamzaHaider no, it is not helping me because i did not use local storage but thank you for your help

Comment: @RajeshG yes it can if i want, but i just wondering if it should 2 form and cannot be 1 form that's why i ask is it possible, and if it is how it can be.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing two form values as an object so create a view model on server side that matches the object

```
public class MappingViewModel
{
    public MapingUIGH DataHead { get; set; }
    public List<MapingUIGD> DataDet { get; set; }
}
```

and use it as parameter to action method, so the format of data posted from UI matches with parameter

```
public ActionResult SaveData(MappingViewModel viewModel)
```

Comment: how to get data list in datadet then? and how it become in javascript? i'm  sorry i still new, so i am bit confused, would you please tell me more?

Comment: That is completely different question, even you have not mentioned in question what are the properties of `MapingUIGD` or how you are binding it in your form, if you have bind the list correctly in form `$('#frmDetail').serialize()` should work for you.

Comment: sorry i mean, when i use your class like that, how to fill viewModel in ajax, if using 1 serialize i just called the class and call the variable which contain form serialize such as ```var vData = $('#frmDetail').serialize()``` and in ajax ```data : vData``` but if using yours i dont know how. that's why i ask you to elaborate more

Comment: If you are getting form values correctly, `data: { dataHead: vDataHead, dataDet: vDataDet }` will bind correctly with parameter, no change required on UI side.

Comment: bind data is correct but when i debugged controller, data is null. is there anything else that i need to change?

Comment: Have you checked that after serializing the forms, vDataDet contains correct data? if not log and check in browser console vDataDet & vDataDet value after `$('#frmDetail').serialize()` statement.

Comment: it is correct sir, but when i debugged the controller still null.

Comment: Last you can do is use `FromBody` in action, `SaveData([FromBody]MappingViewModel viewModel)` and set content type in Ajax call `Content-type: application/json`.